# Pre-defining named recursive subpatters in regex

Tags: python, regex

**Note:** I know none of this is supported in the existing `re` module, I am using the newer [`regex` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) intended to replace `re` in the future.

I need to build some complex regular expressions, but I would also like those expressions to be maintainable. I don't want anyone to come back to this code months later and have to spend days unravelling or re-writing the expression, myself included. :P

There is some PCRE syntax that I've previously used to accomplish this, eg:

```
/
(?(DEFINE)
  (?<userpart> thomas | richard | harold )
  (?<domainpart> gmail | yahoo | hotmail )
  (?<tld> com | net | co\.uk )
  (?<email> (?&userpart)@(?&domainpart)\.(?&tld) )
)
^ To: \s+ .* \s+ < (?&email) > $
/ix
```

Will match the line: `To: Tom Selleck <thomas@gmail.com>`

**Note²:** I'm not trying to match email addresses, it's just an example.

I see that the `regex` module has implemented recursive patterns, and named recursive patterns, but it does not seem to like `(?(DEFINE) ... )` syntax, giving the error `unknown group at position 10`.

Is it at all possible to pre-define named patterns like this in Python?

Comment: did you try to write for example: `(?<tld> com | net | co\.uk ){0}`

Comment: Recursion is different from a define construct. Also, it is not mentioned in the [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) that the regex module supports it.

Comment: I don't see anything like that in the docs for regex, so I think the answer is no.  Am I right that you can still achieve the effect that you want in terms of match behavior, you just want to write the regex in a more readable way?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte you win the super. Removed the `(?(DEFINE) ...)` block, added `{0}` to the ends of the patterns, and it worked! If you want to formalize that into an answer I'll gladly accept.

Comment: Youpi!!! <°))))))))))>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there is no syntax like the Perl/PCRE `(?(DEFINE)....)` in the new python regex module, you can use this trick (I think that it works in Ruby too):

```
import regex

pattern = r'''
  (?<userpart> thomas | richard | harold ){0}
  (?<domainpart> gmail | yahoo | hotmail ){0}
  (?<tld> com | net | co\.uk ){0}
  (?<email> (?&userpart)@(?&domainpart)\.(?&tld) ){0}

  ^ To: \s+ .* \s+ < (?&email) > $
'''
```

Since you add the quantifier `{0}`, you obtain zero width group definitions you can put everywhere.

Comment: This could be used to add comments if the flavor of regex doesn't support the comment group

Comment: @Denomales: Why not. Happy to see you again!