# Inject code after X paragraphs but avoiding tables

Tags: php, regex, explode

i would like to inject some code after X paragraphs, and this is pretty easy with php.

```
public function inject($text, $paragraph = 2) {

    $exploded = explode("</p>", $text);
    if (isset($exploded[$paragraph])) {
        $exploded[$paragraph] = '
            MYCODE
            ' . $exploded[$paragraph];

        return implode("</p>", $exploded);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

But, I don't want to inject my `$text` inside a `<table>`, so how to avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: do not parse html with regex

Comment: If you saw the original short answer, I considerably expanded it, but have to go now. :)

Comment: @oscar I added Method 1 which is better than last night's method. The idea woke me up and it now looks like Hamza had a similar idea to use a (*SKIP)(*FAIL) but from glancing at it it's not the same idea---perhaps more compact, will go read Hamza's idea in detail now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sometimes a bit crazy, sometimes I go for patterns that are lazy, but this time I'm going for something hazy.

```
$input = 'test <table><p>wuuut</p><table><p>lolwut</p></table></table> <p>foo bar</p> test1 <p>baz qux</p> test3'; # Some input
$insertAfter = 2; # Insert after N p tags
$code = 'CODE'; # The code we want to insert

$regex = <<<'regex'
~
# let's define something
(?(DEFINE)
   (?P<table>                     # To match nested table tags
      <table\b[^>]*>
         (?:
            (?!</?table\b[^>]*>).
         |
            (?&table)
         )*
      </table\s*>
   )
   (?P<paragraph>                 # To match nested p tags
      <p\b[^>]*>
         (?:
            (?!</?p\b[^>]*>).
         |
            (?&paragraph)
         )*
      </p\s*>
   )
)
(?&table)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)           # Let's skip table tags
|
(?&paragraph)                     # And match p tags
~xsi
regex;

$output = preg_replace_callback($regex, function($m)use($insertAfter, $code){
    static $counter = 0; # A counter
    $counter++;
    if($counter === $insertAfter){ # Should I explain?
        return $m[0] . $code;
    }else{
        return $m[0];
    }
}, $input);

var_dump($output); # Let's see what we've got
```

<kbd>[**Online regex demo**](http://regex101.com/r/mI7mE7)</kbd>
<kbd>[**Online php demo**](https://eval.in/138731)</kbd>

**References:**

- [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)
- [What does the "[^][]" regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845014/what-does-the-regex-mean)
- [Verbs that act after backtracking and failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992984/verbs-that-act-after-backtracking-and-failure)
- [Is there a way to define custom shorthands in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149814/is-there-a-way-to-define-custom-shorthands-in-regular-expressions)

Comment: Nice idea! I always like your work. The idea of a preg_replace_callback with a (*SKIP)(*FAIL) woke me up, and I worked on it and added it to my solution before seeing your answer. But it looks very different from your answer, which I'll now go read in detail.

Comment: @HamZa there is only a problem: if there are no paragraph outside the table, I receive a "no data received" error from the browser..

Comment: @OscarFanelli [It does work](https://eval.in/142468) on my end. So I think the problem is elsewhere

Comment: @OscarFanelli So there's no problem?

Comment: Now it's ok, but maybe there could be a better way to avoid the problem, editing the regex. However i'm not so good with them :(

Comment: @OscarFanelli I'm definitely sure there is no problem with the regex. So to break this certainty of mine, you need to show me a demo where it fails. From there on I could work on something.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** It was late last night.

1. The `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` was neat but I am now **adding a better idea (Method 1).**
2. Also improved Method 2 to replace the `strstr` with a faster `substr`

**METHOD 1: `preg_replace_callback` with `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`** (better)

Let's do a direct replace on the text that is certifiably table-free using a callback to your `inject` function.

Here's a regex to match table-free text:

```
$regex = "~(?si)(?!<table>).*?(?=<table|</table)|<table.*?</table>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)~";
```

In short, this either matches text that is a complete non-table or matches a complete table and fails.

Here's your replacement:

```
$injectedString = preg_replace_callback($regex,
        function($m){return inject($text,$m[0]);},
            $data);
```

Much shorter!

**And here's a demo of $regex** showing you how it matches elements that don't contain a table.

```
$text = "<table> to 
</table>not a table # 1<table> to 
</table>NOT A TABLE # 2<table> to 
</table>";
$regex = "~(?si)(?!<table>).*?(?=<table|</table)|<table.*?</table>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)~";
$a = preg_match_all($regex,$text,$m);
print_r($m);
```

**The output:** `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => not a table # 1 [1] => NOT A TABLE # 2 ) )`

Of course the html is not well formed and $data starts in the middle of a table, all bets are off. If that's a problem let me know and we can work on the regex.

**METHOD 2**

Here is the first solution that came to mind.

In short, I would look at using `preg_split` with the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag.

The basic idea is to isolate the tables using a special `preg_split`, and to perform your injections on the elements that are certifiably table-free.

**A. Step 1:** split `$data` using an unusual delimiter: your delimiter will be a full table sequence: from `<table` to `</table>`

This is achieved with a delimiter specified by a regex pattern such as `(?s)<table.*?</table>`

Note that I am not closing `<table` in case you have a class there.

So you have something like

```
$tableseparator = preg_split( "~(?s)(<table.*?</table>)~", $data, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE );
```

The benefit of this `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag is that the whole delimiter, which we capture thanks to the parentheses in the regex pattern, becomes an element in the array, so that we can isolate the tables without losing them. [See demo of this at the bottom.] This way, your string is broken into clean "table-free" and "is-a-table" pieces.

**B. Step 2:** Iterate over the $tableseparator elements. For each element, do a

`if(substr($tableseparator[$i],0,6)=="<table")`

If `<table` is found, leave the element alone (don't inject). If it isn't found, that element is clean, and you can do your `inject()` magic on it.

**C. Step 3:** Put the elements of `$tableseparator` back together (implode just like you do in your `inject` function).

So you have a two-level explosion and implosion, first with preg_split, second with your explode!

Sorry that I don't have time to code everything in detail, but I'm certain that you can figure it out. :)

**`preg_split` with `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` demo**

Here's a demo of how the preg_split works:

```
$text = "Hi@There@@Oscar@@@@";
$regex = "~(@+)~";
$a = preg_split($regex,$text,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($a);
```

**The Output:** `Array ( [0] => Hi [1] => @ [2] => There [3] => @@ [4] => Oscar [5] => @@@@ [6] => )`

See how in this example the delimiters (the @ sequences) are preserved? You have surgically isolated them but not lost them, so you can work on the other strings then put everything back together.

Comment: very nice! I absolutely have to try it

Comment: @OscarFanelli Thanks for your comment. It's mad!!! I woke up with this idea of preg_replace_callback with (*SKIP)(*FAIL), worked furiously on it and saw that the mighty Hamza had posted one a short one before. But the answers look quite different so now you have a portfolio to choose from for your code. :)

Comment: @HamZa But I can upvote you. :) Had gone back to sleep.