# Using previous expression in other group

Tags: php, regex

```
/([a-zA-Z0-9\-])(@)([a-zA-Z0-9\-])/
```

In the regex above group 1 and group 3 contain same expression.
Is there another way to use the same expression in another group beside typing it all over again?

Comment: What language are you using? In PCRE (php)/perl you could use recursion `/([a-z0-9-])@(?1)/i`

Comment: I'm using php, was trying it on regex101 that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: [Oh *really*?](http://regex101.com/r/dG4uV5)

Comment: @user3639768: it's important to put the language tag when you ask something about regex because different languages have different regex features.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte thanks I will keep that in my mind :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to re-use a group, you could [use recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569306/how-to-write-a-recursive-regex-that-matches-nested-parentheses/20569361#20569361):

`/([a-zA-Z0-9\-])(@)(?1)/`

`(?1)` will use the pattern from group 1. Let's now polish your regex:

1. Remove unnecessary group: `/([a-zA-Z0-9\-])@(?1)/`
2. We don't need to escape [a hyphen at the end of a character class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545751/how-to-back-reference-inner-selections-in-a-regular-expression/1553171#1553171): `/([a-zA-Z0-9-])@(?1)/`
3. Let's use [the `i` modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411037/how-do-i-make-this-preg-match-case-insensitive/12411066#12411066): `/([a-z0-9-])@(?1)/i`

<kbd>[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/dG4uV5)</kbd>

Further reading:

- [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)
- [Is there a way to define custom shorthands in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149814/is-there-a-way-to-define-custom-shorthands-in-regular-expressions/18151617#18151617)

Comment: I'm wondering if the `i` modifier is set, do I need `A-Z` inside `[a-zA-Z0-9\-]` ?

Comment: If the `i` modifier is set, we don't need `A-Z` since `a-z` is already specified, it will match case insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PCRE, then you can do this:

```
/([a-zA-Z0-9\-])@(?1)/
                ^
              () not needed around the @ sign
```