# How can i name a group of pattern and use it many times in the whole expression?

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

How can i name a group of pattern and use it many times in the whole expression ?
I have for example some regular expression like :

```
([a][b|c|d|e])[x|y|z][p|q|r]([a][b|c|d|e]) ......([a][b|c|d|e]).... ([a][b|c|d|e])
```

In the above, if you notice [a][b|c|d|e] has been used many a times. I want to name this group to something, so that expression can become more readable. Is that possible ?

I am looking for something so that once the group ([a][b|c|d|e]) is named say "abcdgroup" then i can use "abcdgroup" everywhere in the whole expression. Also, It should not save the result of 1st group, but should solve every time it's used.

Comment: Not aware of any way to do this as a straight regex, but you might be able to utilize the string concatenation features of your language of choice to get the same effect.

Comment: actually, my aim is to somehow reduce the length of the whole expression.

Comment: @VishwasG What tool/language/engine are you using? It's possible in PCRE.

Comment: as3.0 ( actionscript )

Comment: @VishwasG Then the answer is: no, you can't do it directly with regex. A workaround is to use string concatenation like [@esqew](http://stackoverflow.com/users/269970/esqew) said. Here's a PCRE/perl regex for the ideal situation: `(?P<digits>\d+)(?P<foo>foo)(?&digits)(?&foo)(?&digits)`. [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mH1uJ4/1).

Comment: Basically it's called recursion. A nice explanation can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149814/is-there-a-way-to-define-custom-shorthands-in-regular-expressions/18151617#18151617)

Comment: How string concatenation is related to this ?

Comment: @VishwasG I'm not an AS developer so let's talk in pseudo code. You might use `String digitRegex = "\d+"; String fooRegex = "foo"; String finalRegex = digitRegex + fooRegex + digitRegex";` instead of `String finalRegex = "\d+foo\d+";`